# TwentyEleven horizontal submenu

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, sub-menu

I am trying to get the 2nd level menu items be listed horizontally (for Twenty Eleven theme on Wordpress 3.3 beta 4). I've tried modifying

```
#access ul li:hover > ul {
         display: block; }
```

to `display: inline-block;`

but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try positioning the UL absolutely and give a distance from "top", eg:

```
#access ul li > ul {
  position:absolute;
}

#access ul li:hover > ul {
  top: 2em; /*This needs to be enough to push it below the main menu */
}
```

You might also need to float the LIs within that left, or display them inline, eg:

```
#access ul li:hover > ul li {
  float:left;
}
```

or

```
#access ul li:hover > ul li {
  display:inline;
}
```

Without seeing your HTML and CSS it's hard to help, but I hope this helps to get you on the right path.